# Advice for installation on Probook 450 G

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 14 on my new HP Probook 450 G2 with windows 7.
At the step "Installation Type", I don't have the choice "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7". I looked at the choice "something else" but I don't understand well what to do.

When I try Ubuntu on my USB live it works well. And the hard drive is divided like this:
sda1 : system
sda2 : HP recovery
sda3 : HP tools.

Do you know why I don't have the choice "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7" and how to do a not too comlicated installation?
Moreover do you know any problem with this model of computer or this brand?

Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just simply don't have space to allocate extra partitions.

You may resize your existed partitions by using [GParted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655558/gparted-resize-move-options) with Live USB or shrink partition by windows built-in [Disk Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx).
And I would highly recommend you to backup important data before resizing your partitions.

And, personally, I would leave space in the end of disk, It's easier to fill up by later, and then created a extended partition, since only [4 primary partitions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Disk_partitioning) or 3 + 1 extended partition are possible, and Linux works perfectly fine in logic partitions (you can have unlimited logic partitions in extended primary partition).

Good luck.